# Erro no findOne do Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

estou recebendo `Error: Invalid argument to findOne(): 'texto pesquisado'` ao executar o `findOne` do Mongoose:

```
const User = mongoose.model('users', mySchema);
const query - 'texto pesquisado';

User.findOne(query, function(err, data) {
    if (err) return console.log('ERROR: ', err);
    return console.log('DATA: ', data);
});
```

Não estou encontrando o motivo desse erro, pois os argumentos da função estão aparentemente corretos. Alguém sabe o que pode estar ocorrendo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O findOne espera um documento/objeto como parâmetro, não somente uma String como você passou. Verifica no exemplo abaixo:

```
const User = mongoose.model('users', mySchema);
const query = 'texto pesquisado';

User.findOne({nomecoluna: query}, function(err, data) {
    if (err) return console.log('ERROR: ', err);
    return console.log('DATA: ', data);
});
```

Você pode encontrar mais exemplos na documentação do mongoose 
[mongoosejs.com](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html)

Comment: Não entendi qual a relação de sua resposta com o erro que estou recebendo...

Comment: Error: Invalid argument to findOne(): 'texto pesquisado' ao executar o  findOne do Mongoose:

Você só ta passando o valor que quer buscar no documento 
const query - 'texto pesquisado'; que ainda está errado
const query = 'texto pesquisado'; esse é o certo

Aqui também você errou 
User.findOne(query, function(err, data) {}
você só passou como argumento a const query sem informa o nome da colula a buscar a informação da const query
O certo seria
User.findOne({nomecoluna: query}, function(err, data) {}

({nomecoluna: query} e assim que você passa argumento ! .

Comment: ah sim... agora percebi meu erro. Eu peguei um trecho de código com `find()` e apenas substitui pelo `findOne()` sem perceber que no `findOne()` é passado um objeto com `nameField: value` em lugar de apenas a string a ser pesquisada. Obrigado!